# What's the purpose of setting their clock to 10 mins?

Tags: tenet

In the movie, Red and Blue team set their clock to 10 mins
before entering Stalsk-12 Battle field:

[image]

What's the purpose of setting their clock to 10 mins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the assault has already taken place in the future, they have intel that there's a bomb in the facility that will explode precisely ten minutes after they land. The goal is to assault the facility from both directions in time, then get their troops out before the explosion happens.

> to ensure that Ives is in place to set off the bomb at the right time.

There's some expository dialogue in [the script](https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/tenet-2020.pdf) that explains the watches.

> **IVES (CONT'D):** *The bomb is in the rock high above to trigger a collapse, sealing the
> cavern.*
>
> **RED SOLDIER 2:** *How do we defuse the bomb up there?*
>
> **IVES:** *We don’t. The explosion takes place as planned, exactly ten minutes
> after our landing. Everything is synchronized to that explosion.
> Both teams have countdown watches – ours counts down from ten at landing, to zero at the explosion*
>
> ...
>
> **WHEELER:** Ten at the explosion, to zero at our extraction. If you are not at
> the LZ by zero, you are not leaving.
>
> [BACK TO RED-TEAM BRIEFING]
>
> **IVES:** Our job is to fail to defuse the bomb, while the splinter unit achieves its task undetected.